# xcode wcf object as parameter

Tags: xcode, wcf, object, parameters

I'm trying to call a WCF Service from XCODE that has an Object as parameter instead of string or long. I'm always using a couple of services wish have simple Parameter like string or long and they work perfectly. But when I using the Object as Parameter I can get to the C# Service on my Windows Box but the Parameter is always a new C# object with no values in it. 
The Object I'am using looks like this one:

```
[DataContract]
public class MobileComplaint
{
    [DataMember]
    public long MobileComplaintID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string CaseNo { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string CreationUser { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string DaysSinceLastChange { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string State { get; set; }
}
```

The Function looks like this one:

```
[OperationContract]
MobileComplaint Save(long UserID, MobileComplaint mc);
```

For the normal Functions I use Messages that looks like this one:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
 xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> 
 <SOAP-ENV:Body> 
 <OpenComplaint xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"> 
 <MobileComplaintID>3</MobileComplaintID> 
 </OpenComplaint> 
 </SOAP-ENV:Body> 
 </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

**The Question** is now how do I have to write Parameter for this Message!

**Second Question** is it necessary to add all parameter for the object or is it ok when I just fill those I need.

**THX for help**

I always tried the following two:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> 
<SOAP-ENV:Body> 
<Save xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"> 
 <UserID>229001</UserID> 
<mc xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Ibs.MobileDefectDetection.Vo" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
<a:MobileComplaintID>29292</MobileComplaintID> 
</mc> 
</Save> 
</SOAP-ENV:Body> 
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>



<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> 
<SOAP-ENV:Body> 
<Save xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"> 
 <UserID>229001</UserID> 
<mc> 
<MobileComplaintID>29292</MobileComplaintID> 
</mc> 
</Save> 
</SOAP-ENV:Body> 
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

OK I had I typo in it:

29292

29292 
I missed the "a:"

**Now he fills in some of the Properties in the Object but not all!**

**Does anyone has Idea how this can happen?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it out my self! When you are in a pure .NET Environment the order of the Properties is regardless. But when you go from Xcode to C# the order must be correct. I added now the Order Property to all my DataMember Attributes in the DataContract and followed that order in xcode

```
[DataMember(Order=1)]
```

Michael